# Interpretation of definitions and logical implication in Calculus - e.g. monotonic strictly increasing function

Tags: calculus, functions, logic, definition

I read definitions in Calculus books that often confuse me from a logical perspective. For example, the definition of a monotonic function, e.g. a strictly increasing function, is defined as follows.

$$
\forall x_1, x_2 \in A ~~~ x_1 < x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) < f(x_2) \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Now let's try to forget the intuitive knowledge of a strictly increasing function. This definition should pinpoint a class of functions that are OK and a class of functions that are KO. The functions that are OK are the ones for which the property \eqref{1} is TRUE for every $(x_1, x_2)$ couple in $A$. I've circled the TRUE cases in the attached truth table (only the $\Rightarrow$ part for now; 1) 2) 3) 4) and a) b) c) d) are labels).

[image: TruthTable]

I've been schematic and tried to represent each possible case in the following graphs (the KO cases are marked with an X).

[image]

The cases that puzzle me are the ones marked with question marks. For example, the $\delta)$ case is an allowed case since the property $\eqref{1}$ is TRUE. In fact, $x_1 < x_2$ is false and $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ is true, giving us TRUE for $\Rightarrow$. This is counterintuitive and either is $\eqref{1}$ or my logic wrong. Another allowed case is $\theta)$, for which $x_1 < x_2$ is false and $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ is false (in fact $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$) so $\Rightarrow$ is TRUE.

Admitting for a minute that $\eqref{1}$ may be wrong, I adjusted it as in $\eqref{2}$.

$$
\forall x_1, x_2 \in A ~~~ x_1 < x_2 \Leftrightarrow f(x_1) < f(x_2) \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

This adjustment gets rid of the $\delta$ case but not the $\theta$ one, so I'm logically confused. What is the correct definition of a strictly increasing function if not $\eqref{1}$? How should I interpret definitions like $\eqref{1}$ from a logical point of view?

I've never studied logic before (but sooner or later I will)... for now please help me sleep peacefully tonight :D.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: You cannot forget $\forall x, y \ldots$. Consider case $\delta$: you have $x_2 < x_1$ and $f(x_2) > f(x_1)$ (assuming I've read well the sketch). This means that, with $x=x_2$ and $y=x_1$ we have a pair $x,y$ such that $x < y$ and not $f(x) < f(y)$. Thus the conditional is *false* and the definition implies that $f$ is **not** increasing.

Comment: You are right, I was half-forgetting $\forall x_1, x_2$. $\forall x_1, x_2$ means fixing a $x_1$ and a $x_2$, do the implication involved, and then connect with a $\wedge$ all the implications. For a function like $\delta$ there is a "moment" in which $x_1$ and $x_2$ swap places, and this is enough for the overall implication being wrong. The same for $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a strictly increasing function, every pair $(a,~b)$ must pass the test.  The test is that if $a < b$ then $f(a) < f(b)$.

In your plot (d), you've shown a pair that passes the test: the pair $(x_1,~x_2)$.  But the plot is clearly not strictly increasing.  This suggests that there must be a pair that doesn't pass the test.  What about $(x_2,~x_1)$?

Answer (score 1):

A statement of the form $\forall (x_1,x_2){\in}A^2~\big[P(x_1,x_2)\Rightarrow Q(x_1,x_2)\big]$ is satisfied if for *every* possible pair of values from the interval either $Q(x_1,x_2)$ is true or $P(x_1,x_2)$ is false.   That is to say *when ever* $P(x_1,x_2)$ is true, then $Q(x_1,x_2)$ must be true too — and *when ever* $P(x_1,x_2)$ is false then, the implication is satisfied.

Finding single examples of the implication holding (particularly those where the antecedent is false) will not suffice to demonstrate satisfaction of the whole statement; the implication has to hold for *all* cases.

(Although, a single counter example *will* suffice to show that the statement is unsatisfied.)